# Visual Complex Analysis - Transformation and Rotations of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I have just learned about the transformation and rotations of complex numbers from the Visual complex analysis book. Example on page 18, makes total sense:

$$\mathcal R_a^{\theta}(z) = (\mathcal T_v \circ \mathcal R_0^{\theta} \circ \mathcal T ^{-1}_v)(z)$$

And thus one can show that a single rotation can be decomposed into the following:

$$\mathcal R_a^{\theta}(z) = (\mathcal T_k \circ \mathcal R_0^{\theta})(z) $$

where $k=a(1-e^{i\theta})$

Conversely one can show that rotaiton about the origin and then translation can be expressed as a single rotation, i.e. that:

$$(\mathcal T_v \circ \mathcal R_0^a)(z) = ?$$

And this is my problem. I cannot show that it is equal to a single rotation. I cannot find that value of $c$...

Comment: I mean algebraically I see that $a= k/(1-e^{i\theta})$ and thus if there exists a single rotation for the second equation of the form $\mathcal R_c^a$, then $c=v/(1-e^{i\theta})$, but I am failing to deduce this geometrically. Or in some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between lines, I guess that your question is about the commutation of rotation and translation. It all mounts to the identity

$$(z+a)e^{i\theta}=ze^{i\theta}+ae^{i\theta}.$$

Rotating a translated point is the same as rotating then translating by the rotated vector.

Reciprocally

$$ze^{i\theta}+a=(z+ae^{-i\theta})e^{i\theta}.$$

Rotating then translating a point is the same as translating by the counter-rotated vector, then rotating.

---

Rotating about another point than the origin can be expressed as a combination of a rotation followed by a translation or conversely.

$$(z-a)e^{i\theta}+a=ze^{i\theta}+(a-ae^{i\theta})=(z+(ae^{-i\theta}-a))e^{i\theta}.$$

Answer (score 2):

"rotaiton about the origin and then translation can be expressed as a single rotation": no.

$$e^{i\theta}z+a=ze^{i\theta'}$$ cannot hold.

Take $z=0$: this implies $a=0$.

---

But if you allow rotation about another point $c$,

$$e^{i\theta}z+a=(z-c)e^{i\theta'}+c$$ is obviously solved by

$$\theta'=\theta,\\c=\frac a{1-e^{i\theta}}.$$

Comment: The quoutation actually belongs to the book itself.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: then they mean rotation about anoter point.